# 'NoneType' object is not callable on Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, selenium, ubuntu

I am following [Obeying the Test Goat](http:///www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_working_incrementally.html) by HJWP and deploying my Django app on an Ubuntu Droplets and I come across a problem running my functional test (unit tests all clear).

Details: Python 3.6, Django 2.0.1, Selenium, gecko driver 19.1, remote Ubuntu 16.04, local Window 10 git bash

I've been trying to perform a function test both locally and against the server and got the results below:

Local Test Result

```
File "C:\...\.virtualenvs\superlists\lib\site-
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 81, in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Against Remote Server Result:

```
ValueError at /lists/new
The view lists.views.new_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It 
returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://midsummerseve.life:8000/lists/
```

I think based on the above results, there has to be something wrong with the view function which in this case is

```
def new_list(request):
    list_ = List.objects.create()
    Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'], list=list_)
    return redirect(f'/lists/{list_.id}/')
```

But I have no idea where to further and what makes it return a None object.
Could it be the issue of the models of list and item? Migration steps seem quite smooth though.

```
class List(models.Model):
pass

class Item(models.Model):
text = models.TextField(default='')
list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am also wondering why the server would process a GET request as the specific view function would only be called after user hit ENTER sending off a POST request. Another interesting thing is that i could observe that during FT basically everything worked fine and the console gave me 'OK' after several repetitions of the "NoneType" tracebacks.

Comment: Did you add any custom middleware ?

Comment: @itzMEonTV No custom middleware in this case. All those in settings.py are default and unmodified.

Comment: I just made migrations on the server side and now FT get passed smoothly without any error. FT testing on local behaved as it did before. Still got the 'not callable' stack trace and an 'OK' at the end. Really interesting to see the error get posted and basically affects nothing else during the process. When i was using Django 1.8 i didn't got the error.

Comment: Can u provide more  view code?

Comment: updating to django==2.1.3 resolved the issue

Comment: For reference: issue is https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29353, fixed in https://github.com/django/django/pull/9901